# Objective-c Novice - Needs help with string with variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im trying to get my label to print out "your score is ."

All i can find online is how to print using printf:

```
int score=2;
printf("You scored %i", score);
```

But this does not work when using the setText method. I have also tried

```
labelAnswer.setText:("You scored %i", score);
[labelAnswer setText:("You scored %i", score)];
```

But these do not work. I get an error: "request for member in something not a structure or union"
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[labelAnswer setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %i", score]];
```

will do it. `printf` is a C standard library function, and doesn't interoperate well with the normal Cocoa strings (NSString objects). You should generally steer clear of it here. NSString "literals" should `@"begin with an at sign"`.

You should get one of the intro books for iPhone/Obj-C and start there. Seems like a couple tutorial lessons would help you get rolling.

Comment: also valid: `labelAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %i", score];`

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! I remember coming across that before somewhere, but when i was hunting for a solution it didnt come up.

Answer (score 0):

First, remember always add **@** before your string. This is the way you tell the compiler that this is an NSString, which is, a pre-defined object that has many good features and is really easy to use.

Second, though directly assigning your pointer to things like **@"I_Just_Wrote_A_String"** is acceptable, it is always recommended to use NSString's class methods (such as **stringWithFormat**) or its instance methods (such as **initWithFormat**).

And yes, these methods are slightly different from each other. Methods starting as **initWith** increase objects' retain count up to 1, and you're responsible for releasing them when you are done. But if you use methods starting as **stringWith** instead, you don't need to release them since an autorelease pool will take care of that.

Comment: Nitpick: Sounds like you're recommending wrapping @"string literals" in explicit NSStrings just for consistency. That creates an extra object to no benefit. (The @"literal" is transformed by the compiler into an immutable foundation string object anyways.) If you're creating with a format, of course, that's how it's done.